# Not clear on number of skills my character can have

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, sorcerer, half-elf

I'm starting a half-elf sorcerer character with a custom background.  If I read correctly, as half-elf I get any two skills to choose from (PHB 39).   As a sorcerer I get to select two skills from the list provided (PHB 100).  When customizing a background, I "can replace one feature with any other one, choose any two skills, and choose a total of two tool proficiencies or languages from the sample backgrounds." (PHB 126)

If I'm reading and understanding correctly, that would give me *six* skills I would be proficient in; four could be whatever I choose and two would be restricted to the six listed for sorcerer.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, if your DM is ok with you making a custom Background

Everything you've listed looks good to me, but be wary that your DM might not allow custom backgrounds. Allowing players to create their own backgrounds is useful, and often fitting, but can sometimes serve to lessen the impact of a background on a character. Backgrounds in 5e are as supposed to be used to augment the non-mechanical aspects of your character as much as they are supposed to be used to grant you proficiencies, features, and Inspiration. Bypassing the creative aspects of a background in order to make one more mechanically suited to your character can be seen as a problem by many DMs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is correct.

When customising a background (instead of choosing one of the existing ones), you need to ask your DM first. Most players will pick one of the example backgrounds.